# Kernel of seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space equipped with a seminorm $\|\cdot\|$.

Is the kernel $$ \text{Ker}(\|\cdot\|)=\{ x\in X : \|x\|=0 \} $$ a closed subspace of $X$?

Comment: Do you know whether it is a linear subspace?

Comment: What if seminorm is trivial?

Comment: @DanielFischer The kernel is not necessarily a linear subspace, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of a seminorm is always a linear subspace. By the triangle inequality, for $x,y \in \ker \:\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$ we have

$$\lVert x+y\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert = 0 + 0 = 0,$$

hence $x+y \in \ker \:\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$. And by homeogeneity, for $x\in \ker\: \lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ (or whatever the scalar field is) we have

$$\lVert \lambda x\rVert = \lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot\lVert x\rVert = \lvert\lambda\rvert\cdot 0 = 0,$$

so $\lambda x\in \ker\:\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$.

Whether the kernel of a seminorm is a *closed* subspace depends. In general, it isn't, but it certainly is closed - as the preimage of the closed set $\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ - if the seminorm is continuous. But continuity of the seminorm is not necessary for the kernel to be closed. Lower semicontinuity is sufficient (the kernel is also the preimage of the closed set $(-\infty,0] \subset \mathbb{R}$, and for lower semicontinuous functions, the preimages of such sets are closed). But also lower semicontinuity is not a necessary condition. Consider a Banach space $(X,\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1)$, and a norm $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ on $X$ that is not equivalent to $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ such that $(X,\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2)$ is also a Banach space. Then $\ker \:\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2 = \{0\}$ is a closed subspace of $(X,\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1)$, but $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ is not lower semicontinuous with respect to the topology $\tau$ induced by $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$. For on Banach spaces (more generally, on barrelled spaces) every lower semicontinuous seminorm is continuous, and if $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$ were continuous with respect to $\tau$, the open mapping theorem would yield the equivalence of the two norms.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is a closed subspace because
$$ \|x\|\leq \|x-x_n\|+\|x_n\|. $$

Comment: That can only be used to show that the kernel is closed under the assumption that $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X, p)$ be the seminormed space where the topology is generated by the bases of open balls $\left\{B_r(x): x\in X, r>0\right\}$. Then, for every point $x_0\in X$ such that $\epsilon_0:=p(x_0)\neq 0$, the open ball $B_{\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}}(x_0)$ lies entirely in $X\setminus p^{-1}(0)$, the complement of the kernel. So the complement is open, and the kernel is closed.

However, the above deduction is under the seminormed topology. If you are asking whether the kernel of seminorm $p$ is closed under a given normed topology, then that's another story.